# Need help understanding this regex

Tags: regex

I found this problem on regexone.com - http://regexone.com/problem/matching_phone_numbers. Write a single regular expressions that matches the number and captures the proper area code.

```
Exercise 2: Matching Phone Numbers

Task      Text          Capture   Groups     
Capture 415-555-1234    415      Success
Capture 650-555-2345    650      Success
Capture (416)555-3456   416      Success
Capture 202 555 4567    202      Success
Capture 4035555678      403      Success
Capture 1 416 555 9292  416      Success
```

Here the expression `(\d{1}?(\d{2}))` captures the area code but what I need to understand is my first group is for 1 digit only and is optional.  And my second group should hold only 2 digits. How did capture 3 digits?

Comment: Huh? Because 1 + 2 = 3? It will match either 2 digits (`\d{2}`) or 3 (`\d{1}\d{2}`)

Comment: [*Quantifier: {1}? Exactly 1 time (meaningless quantifier)*](https://regex101.com/r/xK6sE4/1)

Comment: @h2ooooooo What about the last number 1 416 555 9292? It skipped 1 and captured 416

Comment: @MukundGandlur Because it can't possible match 2 digits after eachother (and it has to be *at least* 2), so it skips to the next time it's possible to match 2 consecutive digits. Really `\d{2,3}` should work just as well.

Comment: Ok I get it. Thanks!!!

Comment: Thought it matches exactly 2 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Mateen Ulhaq's answer, the first group is the entire regex given. As for your other question, there doesn't seem to be any reason to split the digit matching into two groups. It would make sense if area codes occasionally were two-digit, but it's not the case in any of the given example. The regex `(\d{3})` gives the expected output for all of them as well and is shorter and simplier.

Answer (score 2):

Your first group is given by the first `(`.

```
(\d{1}?(\d{2}))
^             ^
|             |
|             |
everything inside here
```

Thus, it captures all three digits.

---

Perhaps a better way of writing your regex would be:

```
(\d{2,3})
```

which captures all two or three-digit numbers.

If you wish to capture the first digit as well (i.e. `1 800`):

```
((\d\s)?\d{2,3})
```

Comment: You should clarify in your answer that the first group includes all three digits, and that the second group captures the last 2 digits of the first group.  The "Captures"